# Escape quotes in a variable with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I use this code to genefate html

```
echo "<input type='button' onclick=\"myFunc('$param');\" />";
```

Everything would be OK unless $param contains `'` or `"` character. How should it be implemented to handle these situations?

ps. mysql_real_escape_string($param) won't work correctly, when a user entered `"`.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of functions that could be used:

```
<?php
$string = 'string test"';

echo htmlentities($string) . "\n";
echo addslashes($string) . "\n";
```

They produce the following:

```
string test&quot;
string test\"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are relying on user input, use `htmlentities($param, ENT_QUOTES);`

See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: No problemo @eldorjon . Receiving a thanks for something done 9 years ago feels nice. Also, I wouldn't know the answer today, haha.

Answer (score 5):

As Damien said; use addslashes :)

```
$param=addslashes($param);
echo "<input type='button' onclick=\"myFunc('$param');\" />";
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass variable from `htmlspecialchars($pram,ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: ENT_QUOTES should be without $ sign I believe, since it's constant, not variable

Answer (score 2):

Whenever thinking about escaping, you always need to ask
**"In which context do I want to escape?"**
Because escaping is essentialy making sure the input is not interpreted in the special meaning of the target, but literaly

Do **not** use addslashes, since it's contextless

If you are inserting the string into HTML, use

```
htmlspecialchars($argument, ENT_QUOTES)
```

as mentioned.

The **onclick** content part is technicaly JavaScript, so it might be appropriate to escape *the content* with json_encode (it's side-effect is JavaScript-specific escaping). Similarly should you have style attribute, you'd want to escape *the content* with

```
addcslashes($s, "\x00..\x2C./:;<=>?@[\\]^`{|}~")
```

(source: http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fphpfashion.com%2Fescapovani-definitivni-prirucka&ie=UTF8&sl=cs&tl=en)

**Summary**
Use

```
$param = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($param), ENT_QUOTES)
```

and then you can safely include it into the HTML string

Answer (score 1):

first do

```
// only for the GUY who didn't read the complete answer :(
$param=addslashes($param);
```

then write code in simple HTML

```
<input type='button' onclick="myFunc(<?php echo $param?>);" />
```

**Note:** `mysql_real_escape_string` works when we handle with mysqltry with `addslashes`

Comment: How would your code example help if $param contained a `"` or a `'`?

Comment: @Nick could u read complete answer ?? i said try with `addslashes`

Comment: @Daric: Have tou read the last sentence: *try with `addslashes`* ?. Granted, @diEcho could have put this in the code too, but it is there!

Comment: @Felix: That was copied later from another answer and he still did not improved. just copied at the end of answer.

Comment: @Daric...can u see i edited first time now.... *@Daric* without knowing anything how can u claim that???

Comment: Btw. I gave +1 for not echoing HTML and I read the answer to the end ;)

Comment: @Daric u have no such reputation so that u can see the edited code..thats not my fault

Comment: @diEcho: I think one can always see the revision history... that does not depend on reputation.

Comment: @Felix Kling i dont know that, if he can see then he must see the revision history

Comment: @Daric see this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5686118/revisions. only 2 times edited

Comment: Then that was unstructured answer I see you improved. There is no reason to keep downvote

Comment: @Daric that is not unstructured... i answered in the way question is put up

Comment: @diEcho @Felix  I didn't downvote, btw.  The answer was poorly constructed, so I commented on it.  That's the point of the comment system, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="showTable(&#039;'.$table.'&#039;)">'.$table.'</a>';
```

It's not necessary to use backslaches for escaping when using single quote for echo. Single quote have my vote to work with both php and javascript + html tag.